# Invalid cast when returning mysql LAST_INSERT_ID() (mysql version >= 5.5.32). Using dapper

Tags: mysql

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Install mysql version >= 5.5.32
2. Execute insert cmd and then select select LAST_INSERT_ID(). Exemple:

   using (var items = SqlMapper.QueryMultiple(_db_connection,
                   @"insert into images set image_extension = @extension, image_group = @group, image_main = @main; select LAST_INSERT_ID();",
                   new { extension = extension, group = group, main = main }
                   ))
                   {
                       imageID = items.Read().Single();
                   }
3. if you do the same thing, only with mysql version 5.5.28 then all will work fine

I used a machine with windows server 2008 x64. MySql Server versions 5.5.32 and 5.5.28. Dapper version 1.13. MySql Connector for .NET version 6.7.4

Comment: Does the returned type of last-insert-id change between versions? If so, it is possible that this will be fixed automatically in the next drop (I added better conversion support) - until then, maybe an explicit cast in the SQL?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved with the use of cast functions in mysql